# Problem accumulating/appending values in an array using recursion with Go

Tags: arrays, go

First of all, this is my first non-dummy program using Go. Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Code description:

I want to retrieve all the information from an API where the information is being paginated. So I want to iterate through all the pages in order to get all the information.

This is what I did so far:

I have the these two functions:

```
func request(requestData *RequestData) []*ProjectsResponse {

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    projects := []*ProjectsResponse{}
    innerRequest(client, requestData.URL, projects)

    return projects
}

func innerRequest(client *http.Client, URL string, projects []*ProjectsResponse) {

    if URL == "" {
        return
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", URL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Request creation failed with error %s\n", err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Private-Token", os.Getenv("API_KEY"))

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    log.Printf("Executing request: %s", req.URL)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    var response ProjectsResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &response)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unmarshalling failed with error %s\n", err)
    }

    projects = append(projects, &response)
    pagingData := getPageInformation(res)
    innerRequest(client, pagingData.NextLink, projects)
}
```

Undesired behavior:

The values in the `projects []*ProjectsResponse` array are being appended on each iteration of the recursion, but when the recursion ends I get an empty array list. So, somehow after the `innerRequests` ends, in the `project` variable inside the `request` method I get nothing.

Hope somebody and spot my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return the slice at the end of the recursion or pass it and assign by reference. When the recursion ends, you are still left with the original slice header you started with, despited the underlying array actually having the data.

Comment: Sorry ppl, not following completely. Anyone willing to update my code? I'll accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that all of your project objects are scoped to the function so they no longer exist when the function ends. I don't think you need your projects to exist before you call innerRequest, so you should probably just have that method return the projects. I think something like this should work...

```
func innerRequest(client *http.Client, URL string) []*ProjectsResponse {

if URL == "" {
    return nil
}

//More code...

pagingData := getPageInformation(res)
return append([]*ProjectsResponse{&response}, innerRequest(client, pagingData.NextLink)...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The confusion lies in the way a `slice` is handled in Go. [Here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) is the in-depth explanation, but I will abbreviate.

The common misconception is that the `slice` you pass around is a *reference* to the `slice`, which is false. The actual variable you operate on when you handle a slice is known as a *slice header*. This is a simple `struct` with a *reference* to the underlying array under the covers and follows Go's *pass by value* rules, i.e. it is *copied* when passed to a function. Thus, if it is not returned, you won't have the updated header.

Returning data from recursion follows a straightforward pattern. Here is a basic example. I'm also including a version that doesn't require a return, but operates on the slice as a reference, which will modify the original. (Note: Passing around slice pointers is generally not considered idiomatic Go)

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/v5XeYpH1VlF

```
// correct way to return from recursion
func addReturn(s []int) []int {
    if finalCondition(s) {
        return s
    }
    s = append(s, 1)
    return addReturn(s)
}

// using a reference
func addReference(s *[]int) {
    if finalCondition(*s) {
        return
    }
    *s = append(*s, 1)
    addReference(s)
}

// whatever terminates the recursion
func finalCondition(s []int) bool {
    if len(s) >= 10 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: After all that, I probably should have just marked it as a duplicate of the many slice header copy issues people have posted...

Comment: If it's a duplicate, why don't point me to the duplicate question with is answer? It's somewhat pedantic your behavior specially when I'm learning a new language.  Empathy -1

Comment: @Marcote Because the duplicate would only explain what is happening with the slice headers, not what is missing from your recursion. Going over both is more useful to you.

Comment: @Marcote I hadn't noticed the term "pedantic" in your comment until I re-read it just now. Not that I disagree, but one thing you'll find with Go specifically, is that the language itself is minimalistic by design and that the language specification is _actually_ human readable (https://golang.org/ref/spec) and the documentation is so superb. As a result of this, you'll find _many_ Q/A on SO and many of us answering will seem apathetic at times, and many answers simply refer to the spec or documentation. It's nothing personal, it's just a quirk with the language, and thus its community.